# Get preferences older than the most recent entry using java.util.prefs.Preferences.get

Tags: java, preferences

With the java.util.prefs.Preferences API is it possible to get historic results which are older than the last entry?

eg if you had

```
prefs.put("key", "value1");
prefs.put("key", "value2");

return prefs.get("key");
```

will return "value2"
Can I ever get "value1" ?

If no then what is the best alternative to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone can do better I am happy to accept their answer, in the mean time:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class RecentStrings
{
    private final Preferences prefs;
    private final int noRecent;
    private static final int defaultNo = 10;
    private final String indexingKey;

    public RecentStrings()
    {
        this(Preferences.userRoot(), defaultNo, "r");
    }

    public RecentStrings(Preferences prefs, int noRecent, String indexingKey)
    {
        this.noRecent = noRecent;
        this.prefs = prefs;
        this.indexingKey = indexingKey;
    }

    public void setMostRecentString(String file)
    {
        if (!getAllRecentStrings().contains(file))
        {
            for (int i = noRecent-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                prefs.put(indexingKey+(i+1), prefs.get(indexingKey+i, ""));
            }
            prefs.put(indexingKey+0, file);
        }
        else
        {
            removeRecentString(file);
            setMostRecentString(file);
        }
    }

    private void removeRecentString(String file)
    {
        List<String> recents = getAllRecentStrings();
        recents.remove(file);
        for (int i=0; i < noRecent; i++)
        {
            String value;
            if (i < recents.size())
            {
                value = recents.get(i);
            }
            else
            {
                value = "";
            }
            prefs.put(indexingKey+i,value);
        }
    }

    public String getMostRecentString()
    {
        return prefs.get(indexingKey+0, "");
    }

    public List<String> getAllRecentStrings()
    {
        List<String> mostRecent = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String value = prefs.get(indexingKey+i, "");
            if (!value.equals(""))
            {
                mostRecent.add(value);
            }
        }
        return mostRecent;
    }
}
```

Which also handles duplicates and keeps things from most recent to oldest.